WWII movie with a governess working undercover
I'm new here. I want to find this movie I watched many years back. I watched it 10 or may be 15 years back on TV. Here's the movie plot as I can remember. I don't assure that this is the 100% correct flow of events but this is how I remember it. 
It is about world war 2.  An enemy country of Germany wants to send spies to get details of Gestapo army bases. There they select a lady. She's in love with the officer who selected her to the operation. She goes to a house of a leader in the Gestapo army as a governess. There she was able to photograph the secret war designs or plans using a micro film camera. The officer (her lover) comes to fetch her in disguise. They managed to get in a train which arrives Poland as I can remember. When they are close to the border they were being identified and they were shot. But however they managed to cross the border and they escaped. At the end of the film it shows her in her old age and she's being nominated as a war heroine and she's with her husband and family.
Help me to identify this movie.

Sounds like Shining Through from 1992 with Melanie Griffith and Michael Douglas:

1940, Linda Voss is a woman of Irish, Jewish-German parentage who loves the movies, especially films about war and spies. She gets a job at a New York law firm, after it's revealed she can speak German, fluently. As secretary and translator to Ed Leland, she begins to suspect that her boss is involved in espionage work. The two become lovers, and when America officially joins the Allies in fighting Hitler, Linda volunteers to go undercover behind enemy lines. 

Everything you've described (her undercover work as a nanny, the microfilm, the border and the end with her as an old woman) is there. Here's the trailer:




Yes it is . Many thanks. I was searching for this many years.
